# Limit session user PHP

Tags: javascript, php

How can I forbid a user from logging in with the same account in two different browsers at the same time.

```
session_start();
// set time-out period (in seconds)
$inactive = 30;
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

if (isset($_SESSION["timeout"])) {
    // calculate the session's "time to live"
    $sessionTTL = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
    if ($sessionTTL > $inactive) {
        session_destroy();
       $redirect_to = isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : '/wordpress';
        $location = str_replace('&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url($redirect_to));;
        header("Location: $location");
    }
    else{
        wp_die('<h1>User is login! </h1>', '', array( 'back_link' => true ));    
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking database, but I'm almost certain that there are many other alternatives that will solve this really simply.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Just set a custom session key when the user is logged and remove it after logout

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to Create a one more table for login logs , in that these will be fields
userID  islogin (default=0)  logintime  useragent

if user is login each time update that login time.

and if user is try to login then we need to check in that if user islogin =1 and logintime < session time .  then die;

You need do that in wordpress i thing

so you need to add code filter for login function.
and on on init update the logintime

Thanks

Comment: include("config.inc.php");
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $id=$current_user->ID;
if(empty(is_user_logged_in()))
{
 $sql = "UPDATE preeduc_users SET LoggedIn='no' WHERE ID=$id";
 mysqli_query($connecDB, $sql);
}
else{
 $sql = "UPDATE preeduc_users SET LoggedIn='login' WHERE ID=$id";
 mysqli_query($connecDB, $sql);
}

Comment: I did this to modify the "LoggedIn" field in the table but when I log off it does not change anything